# How can I make my flutter app run in background without stopping?

Tags: flutter, persistence

I want to make a Flutter application which runs in the background and never stops. I tried so many methods for instance background process, foreground process, Notification and so on but I couldn't find any workable solution.
Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Try this package
https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_background

Request permission to run in background

```
bool hasPermissions = await FlutterBackground.hasPermissions;
```

Then to run it in background use

```
bool success = await FlutterBackground.enableBackgroundExecution();
```

Please note this works only in android